# Javascript tracking script polling

Tags: javascript

I have the JS tracking code below:

```
var jTGateway = "trackingurl";
var jTGatewaySSL = "trackingurl";
var jTDomain = "trackingurl";
var jTUser = "";
var jTPage = "";
var jTProtocol = window.location.protocol;
var jTImage = document.createElement('img');
var jTChatElement; var jTSession; var jTUrl;
jTImage.border = 0;
(function () {
if (jTUser == "") {
    var dt = new Date(); var jTCookie = document.cookie.toString();
    if (jTCookie.indexOf("jtrack") == -1) { jTSession = parseInt(Math.random() *     1000)     + "-" + dt.getTime(); document.cookie = "jtrack=" + jTSession + ";expires=Thu, 31-Dec-2020 00:00:00 GMT; path=/"; }
    jTCookie = document.cookie.toString();
    if (jTCookie.indexOf('jtrack') == -1) { jTSession = ""; } else {
        var s = jTCookie.indexOf("jtrack=") + "jtrack=".length; var e = jTCookie.indexOf(";", s);
        if (e == -1) e = jTCookie.length; jTSession = jTCookie.substring(s, e);
    } 
}
if (jTProtocol == "https:") jTGateway = jTGatewaySSL; if (jTUser != "") jTSession =     jTUser; if (jTProtocol == "file:") jTProtocol = "http:";
})();

function jTTrackPage() {
if (jTPage == "") jTPage = escape(window.location);
jTUrl = jTProtocol + "//" + jTGateway + "/jtrack.ashx?u=" + jTSession + "&d=" + jTDomain;
jTUrl += "&p='" + jTPage + "'&r='" + escape(document.referrer) + "'";
jTImage.src = jTUrl;
}
```

I call it on my page like:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' >
        if (typeof jTTrackPage == 'function') jTTrackPage();
    </script>
```

My question is, is it possible to have it make the call every 10 seconds say? To show that the user is still on tha page. How would I go about that. Any pointers appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use `setInterval`:

```
window.setInterval(jTTrackPage, 10000); // call it every 10 000 ms = 10 s
```

or `setTimeout`:

```
function trackPage() {
    jTTrackPage();
    window.setTimeout(trackPage), 10000); // call the function again in 10 000 ms
}
trackPage();
```

The difference between both is that the first one calls it every 10s, and if one call takes more than 10s (unlikely here) the next one will be triggered just after, without waiting 10s. The second solution solves this problem.

---

You can clear an interval or a timeout using respectively `clearInterval` and `clearTimeout`:

```
var interval = window.setInterval(jTTrackPage, 10000);

window.clearInterval(interval); // <-- stop it

var timeout = window.setTimeout(trackPage, 10000);

window.clearTimeout(timeout); // <-- stop it
```

Comment: Thanks, to confirm then I add this to my .js file. `function trackPage() {
    jTTrackPage();
    window.setTimeout(trackPage), 10000); // call the function agin in 10 000 ms
}` and then in my calling page I use `if (typeof trackPage == 'function') trackPage();` ?